# git: Reset previous commits with parent branch

Tags: git

Suppose I've a `parent` branch in my repository and I make another branch named `derived` from it.

```
git checkout -b derived
```

Now the `derived` branch contains all the commits of my `parent` branch. I add two more commits (commit D1 and D2) to my `derived` branch. My `derived` branch is two commits ahead of `parent` branch.

Now I amend some previous commits in the parent branch and add new commit "Pn". After this, for some reason I want my derived branch to exactly look like this

```
Amended commits from parent branch ---> Pn ---> D1 ----> D2
```

I tried `git rebase parent` from my `derived` branch but it is giving a lot of merge conflicts. Is there any easier way to just reset all the commits before D1 and D2 exactly as the `parent` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such. The commits D1 and D2 rely on every commit before them, including the ones you don't want. But, here are things you can try:

- `git rebase --onto parent derived~3 derived`

  Rebase derived onto the new parent. This sets the merge base explicitly to `derived~3`, the commit that was the HEAD of parent when you created the derived branch.  This will reduce the conflicts, and will avoid reintroducing the old changes.

  Normally, git figures this out automatically, but since you've amended these commits, git can't tell that any relationship exists between them — it can't tell that commit `A'` is an amended variant of commit `A`.
- Cherry pick D1 and D2 onto a new branch

  ```
  git branch derived-new parent
  git checkout derived-new
  git cherry-pick D1 D2
  git branch -m derived derived-old   # Save the old branch until you're ready to delete it
  git branch -m derived-new derived
  ```
- Do an interactive rebase of the derived branch, removing the earlier commits that you don't want, and then seeing what happens. This may also generate a lot of extra conflicts, and force you to `git rebase --abort`, but if it doesn't, you're scott free... Just rebase onto the new parent again, as above

Answer (score 1):

You *do* want to use `git rebase`, you just want it to stop at the point where you used to share commits with the other branch.

That is, you had:

```
...--Pl--Pm--Pn   <-- parent
               \
                D1--D2  <-- derived
```

Since both amending and `git rebase` work by *copying* commits, what you have now is:

```
          Pn'--Po--Pp   <-- parent
         /
---Pl--Pm--Pn   <-- parent@{some-number}
             \
              D1--D2   <-- derived
```

where the memory that `parent` *used to* contain original commit `Pn` is in the reflog for `parent` (and probably in the reflog for `HEAD`).

You can *manually* specify that `git rebase` should stop at `Pn` by using:

```
git rebase --onto parent <hash-of-Pn>
```

(i.e., specify the stopping point for the `<upstream>` as a commit hash, and use `--onto` to make the copies go after the new tip of `parent`).  You can also use commit-relative syntax (`derived~number`) as in [jpaugh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44636486/1256452) to identify `Pn`.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for details.

Git also now has `--fork-point`.  Using `--fork-point`, you can have Git *automatically* root around through the reflog for `parent` to attempt to locate `Pn`.  Here you would run:

```
git rebase --fork-point parent
```

which tells Git to do this rooting-around, and rebase onto `parent` but *drop* commit `Pn`.

Exactly when and whether `--fork-point` works is a bit tricky since reflog entries expire (after 30 or 90 days by default).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow these steps:

1. Check out your `parent` branch

   - `git checkout parent`
2. Create and check out new branch based off the `parent` branch

   - `git checkout -b derived-modified`
3. Use `git cherry-pick` with `derived-modified` checked out to move the new commits from `derived` to `derived-modified` (this will use the modified parent branch with the commits you have modified/added)

   - `git cherry-pick 000aaaa`
   - `git cherry-pick 000bbbb`
   - `git cherry-pick 000cccc`

This will take, for example, the 3 commits you've made to `derived` and move them to `derived-modified`, which contains the modified `parent` branch. Once you've verified the commits are on `derived-modified`, you can delete `derived` and rename `derived-modified`.

More information on `git cherry-pick` is available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).